# Could not load type '...' from assembly 'System.Web, ...'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, app-config, .net-assembly, membership-provider

```
<system.web>
    <profile defaultProvider="TestProfileProvider" inherits="Test.Library.UserAccountProvider.TestUserProfile">
      <providers>
        <add name="TestProfileProvider" type="Test.Library.UserAccountProvider.TestProfileProvider, , Test.Library.UserAccountProvider" connectionStringName="SecurityContext" applicationName="Sigma" applicationContext="XpressPago" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <membership defaultProvider="TestMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="TestMembershipProvider" type="Test.Library.UserAccountProvider.TestMembershipProvider, Test.Library.UserAccountProvider" connectionStringName="SecurityContext" passwordFormat="Clear" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="3" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="Sigma" PasswordResetLimit="45" applicationContext="XpressPago" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="TestRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="TestRoleProvider" type="Test.Library.UserAccountProvider.TestRoleProvider" connectionStringName="SecurityContext" applicationName="Sigma" applicationContext="XpressPago" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="90" maxRequestLength="1048576" useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" appRequestQueueLimit="100"/>
    <machineKey validationKey="196975F087819B74AC983A6D0882E5936BD0F30915A770C58E1177505D72D46F2D6F50BDB35DDF4E904AE01FD3E62726A6E63ADED231644D2D2E595A84AA76B2" decryptionKey="4496E865CAED30BA35BE7B60A06023CC3A13422F15060346" validation="SHA1" />
  </system.web>
```

`TestMembershipProvider` is not showing any error but `TestUserProfile` is showing the following error:

> Could not load type
>   'Test.Library.UserAccountProvider.TestUserProfile' from assembly
>   'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

on statement `return (TestUserProfile)Create(username);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should add the full assembly name (", Test.Library.UserAccountProvider") at the end of 'type' attribute of the line with name="TestProfileProvider" if its the location of your class ?

Like this :

```
  <add name="TestProfileProvider" type="Test.Library.UserAccountProvider.TestProfileProvider, Test.Library.UserAccountProvider" connectionStringName="SecurityContext" applicationName="Sigma" applicationContext="XpressPago" />
```

And the same for the 'inherits' attribute :

```
   <profile defaultProvider="TestProfileProvider" inherits="Test.Library.UserAccountProvider.TestUserProfile, Test.Library.UserAccountProvider">
```

I think Create does not where to pick the class since it tries in "System.Web".
Of course I suppose Test.Library.UserAccountProvider is the right assembly name, fix it if needed...

Comment: In your error message, you can see the type loading has been tried inside of 'System.Web' instead of your own assembly, this is why I suggested that. Maybe the "inherits" directive needs some change too.  As you don't  give a lot of details it's not easy to give you accurate solution.